# How to prevent Ansible / Jinja2 from randomly sorting my config

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I my Ansible config I have settings similar to

```
my_config:
  item1:
    var1: something
    var2: somethingelse
  item2:
    var1: something
    var2: somethingelse
  item2:
    var1: something
    var2: somethingelse
```

In a template file I have something similar to

```
{% for itm in my_config %}
  var1: {{ my_config[itm]['var1']}}
{% endfo %}
```

Now I noticed that Ansible or Jinja2 do not preserve order of my "items". I expected `item1` to come before `item2` etc but as it turns out Ansible or Jinja2 will perform some random sort if the items.

How can I render my template file in order of the config file? Without random sort?

Is it possible to sort on for example `var1` value? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on version of Python (Ansible is written in Python) dictionary keys are sorted or not. So, you can't depend on keys' order, instead you just need to create a list (which is ordered by design):

```
my_config:
- name: item1
  var1: something
  var2: somethingelse
- name: item2
  var1: something
  var2: somethingels
- name: item3
  var1: something
  var2: somethingelse
```

And then in Jinja:

```
{% for item in my_config %}
  var1: {{ item['var1'] }}
{% endfor %}
```